# How do I do a hard refresh of a linked plot in my PowerPoint that is linked to a plot in Excel?

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have a rather large PowerPoint file which I have been using to document my progress on a project for the past year. I have linked numerous plots from two specific Excel files into this PowerPoint file using the typical copy and paste method.

However, I had difficulty with typing, since it would take so long for the words to appear on the slides, and often times parts of words would be incorrectly identified as being misspelled. Since I had to write a lot, I ended up uninstalling all my Microsoft office and then reinstalling to try and resolve the issue.

Although this issue was somewhat ameliorated, a new problem arose. Namely, the plot titles and axes labels of most of my plots have disappeared. I have checked that the plots' link to their origin in the Excel files have not been broken, and have also tried to refresh the plots in order to get back these labels and titles, but this has not helped. Moreover, while some (but not all) plot titles are missing, almost all the axis labels are gone and replaced by integers. The names of my different series are gone as well, and replaced with generic "Series 1" and "Series 2" labels. Interestingly, the data itself in the plots is unaffected.

I do need these titles and axis labels, because they helped organize the information in my plots in conjunction with the notes in my slides. And while it would not be impossible to find every single plots' original copy in Excel and then copy and paste them again into PowerPoint, there are so many plots that this task would take an enormous amount of time (this file has been the product of almost a year's worth of work). Exacerbating this problem is the fact that, because some of the data from different sets look quite similar and were used to make similar looking plots, it is not always obvious to tell which plot originated from where, and may be impossible.

I have tried updating the links to relevant documents in the File tab of the PowerPoint (https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/update-or-remove-a-broken-link-to-an-external-file-29485589-816e-4841-81b7-ff90ae5a2cc4), but this has not worked. Can anybody recommend me any other alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the version history of the file to go back to a point where the plots still had their proper labels. After I identified a version which still had the plot labeling and was the most updated, I restored that version, and then just manually added the few slides that were missing from a locally saved version of the most updated PowerPoint file.